# How to check if the response is a file in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How do check if the response is a file in Flask, or more specifically - if it is a file, how do you get the filename of the response?

The end goal is to get the file extension, i.e., (`.js`, `.css`, `.js.map`, etc...) of the response.

Here's what's avail on `dir(response)`

```
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_ensure_sequence', '_get_mimetype_params', '_is_range_request_processable', '_on_close', '_process_range_request', '_status', '_status_code', '_wrap_response', 'accept_ranges', 'add_etag', 'age', 'allow', 'autocorrect_location_header', 'automatically_set_content_length', 'cache_control', 'calculate_content_length', 'call_on_close', 'charset', 'close', 'content_encoding', 'content_language', 'content_length', 'content_location', 'content_md5', 'content_range', 'content_type', 'data', 'date', 'default_mimetype', 'default_status', 'delete_cookie', 'direct_passthrough', 'expires', 'force_type', 'freeze', 'from_app', 'get_app_iter', 'get_data', 'get_etag', 'get_wsgi_headers', 'get_wsgi_response', 'headers', 'implicit_sequence_conversion', 'is_sequence', 'is_streamed', 'iter_encoded', 'last_modified', 'location', 'make_conditional', 'make_sequence', 'max_cookie_size', 'mimetype', 'mimetype_params', 'response', 'retry_after', 'set_cookie', 'set_data', 'set_etag', 'status', 'status_code', 'stream', 'vary', 'www_authenticate']
```

Checking the type of `response.response`, it is sometimes a `<class 'werkzeug.wsgi.FileWrapper'>`, other times a `<class 'tuple'>` and it *seems* in cases when it is a `tuple` it does not contain `file`

I can do `if hasattr(response.response, 'file'):`

But at this point I'm starting to feel what I'm doing is really jank and not how I should access the filename in the response in Flask.

To sum up, what is the "proper" way to check if the response is a file, and if so, get the file extension?

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Flask code is the on the 'server' side of the client-server relationship.  As a first cut, you need to be looking at the information coming from the client, and in Flask that information is in the **request** object instead of the **response** object.  The **request** object is a **dict** type, so inspecting it with the Python dir() function is not appropriate.

It sounds like you are expecting a filename in a string value of some sort from the browser and want to get the extension part of the name that identifies the file type.  So, here is a simple example that would satisfy your needs:

Assumptions:

1. A template file with a single input field into which you enter the filename.
2. A template file used solely to display the extension of the filename you supplied, along with the original filename.  (I know this is a bit silly, but it gives us the opportunity we need.)
3. A Python-Flask program to display pages and perform the extraction of the extension.
4. A Python program to initiate the application.

This is slightly over-elaborate, but it demonstrates a common Flask project structure.

The template file entry.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Entry Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>

<form action="/entry", method="post">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" name="f_name" value="">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The template file display.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/><br/>
Filename Entered: {{ f_info['filename'] }}
Extension is: {{ f_info['extension'] }}
<br/><br/><br/>

<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Return to Entry Page">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The application program file in the application directory: __init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

fex = Flask(__name__)


@fex.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('entry.html')


@fex.route('/entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_entry():
    f_info = {'filename': None, 'extension': None}
    if 'f_name' in request.form:
        f_info['filename'] = request.form['f_name']
        dot = f_info['filename'].find('.')
        f_info['extension'] = f_info['filename'][dot:]
    return render_template('display.html', f_info=f_info)
```

The run file: fex_run.py

```
from fex_app import fex

fex.run()
```

These files are arranged in the following directory structure:

```
/home/joe
    |
    |-- /fex_proj       (project directory)
        |
        | -- /fex_app   (application directory)
        .    |
        .    | -- /static  (css, js, etc.)
        .    | -- /templates  (html files)
        .    .    |
        .    .    | -- entry.html
        .    .    | -- display.html
        .    |
        .    | -- __init__.py
        .    
        |
        | -- fex_run.py
        | :
```

In the file __init__.py, it's the following code that extracts the extension part of the filename:

```
        dot = f_info['filename'].find('.')
        f_info['extension'] = f_info['filename'][dot:]
```

Of course, your data may be packaged differently, but this example shows the flow from the HTML entry page through to the Flask view function and back to the browser display of the results.